# Best way to run scripts on server (cron even) but expose logs easily

Tags: ruby, linux, windows, automation, cron

Currently we are running some of our small ruby scripts through CI machines like teamcity. But the problem is that teamcity is only free to a certain point and we are reaching that cap. The thing I like about teamcity is the fact that I can define how to run the scripts in it and then have the logs shown in each of the "build" processes so if something goes wrong or I want to verify something I don't have log onto the server and inspect individual files.

The problem is that I need to be able to run the same process at about 4x the capacity I am now, which means I need about 4 times the build agents which leaving the free licensing. Now obviously I could just spin up more teamcity servers but that then becomes a pain.

So my question is, what is another way that I could just basically setup cron processes on linux machines (i have a lot "freely") but then give myself the exposure and ease of access of logs similarly that I gain from teamcity. Obviously I know that setting up cron processes aren't hard but I really want to avoid having to log onto the machine to check and see if my automated processes are running correctly or struggling.

Thanks in advance!

p.s. I also have access to windows machines if there is an easier way to do it there.

Comment: Why not log to a database or [something else](http://www.rsyslog.com)?

Comment: Mainly because for that to work as effectively as I want, i would need to create a front end to be able to easily view them. But you are right that could work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install an open-source CI server like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) if you want to host it yourself. You can also run it on your own machine, though it's usually better to have it always on in the cloud.

Comment: This is a good option but I have had a lot of bad experiences with Jenkins and it's inability to be consistent when trying to back it up and deploy a "duplicate" of it later.